Create a table and pie chart on a confluence page using rest api
How can we pass payload for creating a table and pie chart on a child page in confluence using rest api in java ?
Thanks
Used this api,
`curl -u admin:admin -X PUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"id\":\"26738701\",\"type\":\"page\",\"title\":\"new page\",\"space\":{\"key\":\"RO\"},\"body\":{\"storage\":{\"value\":\"<p>UPDATE This is a new page</p>\",\"representation\":\"storage\"}},\"version\":{\"number\":2}}" http://localost:10080/rest/api/content/2673870

{  
   "id":"26738701",
   "type":"page",
   "title":"new page",
   "space":{  
      "key":"RO"
   },
   "body":{  
      "storage":{  
         "value":"<p>UPDATE This is a new page</p>",
         "representation":"storage"
      }
   },
   "version":{  
      "number":2
   }
}`

But not sure how to pass table, headers and pie chart in the above payload. Kindly help on this please, the pie chart and table will be dynamic every time
